# Tikz Procedure/Function like abstraction?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, programming

I am pretty new to `tikz` but, so I do understand the basics, however, I am truly confused on what's the best way to create a procedure like constructs: there seems to be so many mechanism, and I cannot work out which is best one.

Here is an example drawing that I did. I could figure out LaTeX to make the code more concise and maintainable, but I am not sure which is best construct.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
    body/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,shape=rectangle,draw,ultra thick,minimum height=0.5cm,anchor=south west},
    dimen/.style={<->,>=latex,thin,
    every rectangle node/.style={fill=white,midway}},
    symmetry/.style={dashed,thin},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[array/.style={
rectangle split, 
rectangle split horizontal,
rectangle split parts=#1, 
thick,draw, 
anchor=center,
}]]

\node [array=10, align=center,,minimum width=\textwidth] at (0,0) (pool) {
  \nodepart{one} \rotatebox{-90}{\begin{tabular}{ll}\textbf{\texttt{struct}}\\\texttt{Cons}\end{tabular}}
  \nodepart{two} \rotatebox{-90}{\begin{tabular}{ll}\textbf{\texttt{struct}}\\\texttt{Cons}\end{tabular}}
  \nodepart{three} $\cdots\cdots\cdots$
  \nodepart{four} \rotatebox{-90}{\begin{tabular}{ll}\textbf{\texttt{struct}}\\\texttt{Cons}\end{tabular}}
  \nodepart{five} $\cdots\cdots\cdots$
  \nodepart{six} \rotatebox{-90}{\begin{tabular}{ll}\textbf{\texttt{struct}}\\\texttt{Cons}\end{tabular}}
  \nodepart{seven} $\cdots\cdots\cdots$
  \nodepart{eight} \rotatebox{-90}{\begin{tabular}{ll}\textbf{\texttt{struct}}\\\texttt{Cons}\end{tabular}}
  \nodepart{nine} $\cdots\cdots\cdots$
  \nodepart{ten} \rotatebox{-90}{\begin{tabular}{ll}\textbf{\texttt{struct}}\\\texttt{Cons}\end{tabular}}
};
 \draw (pool.south west) -- ++(0,-1.5) coordinate (A1) -- ++(0,-5pt);
 \draw (pool.south east) -- ++(0,-1.5) coordinate (A2) -- ++(0,-5pt);
 \draw [dimen] (A1) -- (A2) node {$2^{\texttt{LG2\_POOLSIZE}} = 2^{14} = 16,384$};
\node (last) at (0,-1.5) {{\Large \emph{Pool of ``\textup{\texttt{\textbf{struct} Cons}}'' Records}}};

\node [body,minimum width=1cm] (last) at (-6,3.5) { \texttt{car} };
 \draw (last.north west) -- ++(0,0.3) coordinate (A1) -- ++(0,5pt);
 \draw (last.north east) -- ++(0,0.3) coordinate (A2) -- ++(0,5pt);
 \draw [dimen] (A1) -- (A2) node {14b};
\draw[->] (last.south) --  (pool.one north);
\node [body,minimum width=1cm] (last) at (-5,2) { \texttt{cdr} };
 \draw (last.north west) -- ++(0,0.3) coordinate (A1) -- ++(0,5pt);
 \draw (last.north east) -- ++(0,0.3) coordinate (A2) -- ++(0,5pt);
 \draw [dimen] (A1) -- (A2) node {14b};
\draw[->] (last.south) --  (pool.two north);
\node [body,minimum width=1cm] (last) at (-4,3.4) { \texttt{cdr} };
 \draw (last.north west) -- ++(0,0.3) coordinate (A1) -- ++(0,5pt);
 \draw (last.north east) -- ++(0,0.3) coordinate (A2) -- ++(0,5pt);
 \draw [dimen] (A1) -- (A2) node {14b};
\draw[latex->] (last.south) --  (pool.four north);
\node [body,minimum width=1cm] (last) at (-2.5,3) { \texttt{cdr} };
 \draw (last.north west) -- ++(0,0.3) coordinate (A1) -- ++(0,5pt);
 \draw (last.north east) -- ++(0,0.3) coordinate (A2) -- ++(0,5pt);
 \draw [dimen] (A1) -- (A2) node {14b};
\draw[->] (last.south) --  (pool.six north);
\node [body,minimum width=1cm] (last) at (0,2.5) { \texttt{car} };
 \draw (last.north west) -- ++(0,0.3) coordinate (A1) -- ++(0,5pt);
 \draw (last.north east) -- ++(0,0.3) coordinate (A2) -- ++(0,5pt);
 \draw [dimen] (A1) -- (A2) node {14b};
\draw[->] (last.south) --  (pool.eight north);
\node [body,minimum width=1cm] (last) at (2,4) { \texttt{cdr} };
 \draw (last.north west) -- ++(0,0.3) coordinate (A1) -- ++(0,5pt);
 \draw (last.north east) -- ++(0,0.3) coordinate (A2) -- ++(0,5pt);
 \draw [dimen] (A1) -- (A2) node {14b};
\draw[->] (last.south) --  (pool.ten north);
\node [body,minimum width=1cm] (last) at (5,2.5) { \texttt{car} };
 \draw (last.north west) -- ++(0,0.3) coordinate (A1) -- ++(0,5pt);
 \draw (last.north east) -- ++(0,0.3) coordinate (A2) -- ++(0,5pt);
 \draw [dimen] (A1) -- (A2) node {14b};
\draw[->] (last.south) --  (pool.eight north);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is attached; yes, I know it is not too pretty, but that's what I can do at this stage.

My question is then: which abstraction constructs would you recommend for simplifying the above code? More generally, what's in the tikz/LaTeX toolbox and when should one use each of these tools?

[image: Output of the above program]

Comment: I would say that while (La)TeX has macros, not functions, it is quite reasonable to use macros as "procedures", or "routines", or whatever you care to call them. You have to keep in mind that assuming you create your procedure/macro using a command like \newcommand (from LaTeX) or \NewDocumentCommand (from LaTeX3), all you're doing is defining the replacement text of your macro. When you invoke it, the invocation is replaced by the replacement text. Defining and repeatedly invoking a macro is therefore a good way of reusing code, directly analogous to functions in a programming language.

Comment: Indeed, @Hammerite, however, `tikz` has so many other mechanisms: styles, `let` command, iterations, etc. These seem so powerful, but quite confusing to know how to use efficiently.

Comment: I think the best tool to use is the one that you feel you can use most effectively. As you do more, you will probably discover that certain specific things you want to do are best done using one particular feature, and that will prompt you to learn about how that feature works. Thus you will add to your skill set over time and have more options open to you when in the future you come to ask yourself, "what is the best way to approach this task that is before me"?

Comment: When using `tikz` I find that knowing how `pgfkeys` works is of great help. The key-val mechanism is extremely powerful and `tikz` has an incredible amount of hooks that can be used by setting keys (a very powerful example: `insert path`). Another very useful tool is the `\foreach` macro which can help a lot in removing redundancy. As for your specific drawing I think `\matrix` instead of multipart nodes could greatly improve the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is too vague (or broad) in my opinion, but possibilities coming into my mind are

- using `scope` environments
- using styles, pre- or self-defined

For your example instead of writing seven times `\node [body,minimum width=1cm]` you could have written

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
% …
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={body,minimum width=1cm}]% scope and pre-defined style
\node (last) at (-6,3.5) { \texttt{car} };
  \draw (last.north west) -- ++(0,0.3) coordinate (A1) -- ++(0,5pt);
  \draw (last.north east) -- ++(0,0.3) coordinate (A2) -- ++(0,5pt);
  \draw [dimen] (A1) -- (A2) node {14b};
  \draw[->] (last.south) --  (pool.one north);
\node (last) at (-5,2) { \texttt{cdr} };
  \draw (last.north west) -- ++(0,0.3) coordinate (A1) -- ++(0,5pt);
  \draw (last.north east) -- ++(0,0.3) coordinate (A2) -- ++(0,5pt);
  \draw [dimen] (A1) -- (A2) node {14b};
  \draw[->] (last.south) --  (pool.two north);
\node (last) at (-4,3.4) { \texttt{cdr} };
  \draw (last.north west) -- ++(0,0.3) coordinate (A1) -- ++(0,5pt);
  \draw (last.north east) -- ++(0,0.3) coordinate (A2) -- ++(0,5pt);
  \draw [dimen] (A1) -- (A2) node {14b};
  \draw[latex->] (last.south) --  (pool.four north);
\node (last) at (-2.5,3) { \texttt{cdr} };
  \draw (last.north west) -- ++(0,0.3) coordinate (A1) -- ++(0,5pt);
  \draw (last.north east) -- ++(0,0.3) coordinate (A2) -- ++(0,5pt);
  \draw [dimen] (A1) -- (A2) node {14b};
  \draw[->] (last.south) --  (pool.six north);
\node (last) at (0,2.5) { \texttt{car} };
  \draw (last.north west) -- ++(0,0.3) coordinate (A1) -- ++(0,5pt);
  \draw (last.north east) -- ++(0,0.3) coordinate (A2) -- ++(0,5pt);
  \draw [dimen] (A1) -- (A2) node {14b};
  \draw[->] (last.south) --  (pool.eight north);
\node (last) at (2,4) { \texttt{cdr} };
  \draw (last.north west) -- ++(0,0.3) coordinate (A1) -- ++(0,5pt);
  \draw (last.north east) -- ++(0,0.3) coordinate (A2) -- ++(0,5pt);
  \draw [dimen] (A1) -- (A2) node {14b};
  \draw[->] (last.south) --  (pool.ten north);
\node (last) at (5,2.5) { \texttt{car} };
  \draw (last.north west) -- ++(0,0.3) coordinate (A1) -- ++(0,5pt);
  \draw (last.north east) -- ++(0,0.3) coordinate (A2) -- ++(0,5pt);
  \draw [dimen] (A1) -- (A2) node {14b};
  \draw[->] (last.south) --  (pool.eight north);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

or you could have defined a style with `\tikzset`:

```
\tikzset{bodynode/.style={body,minimum width=1cm}}% self-defined style
```

Since you already have used `\tikzset`, you could simply add this to the other definitions.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
% …
\node[bodynode] (last) at (-6,3.5) { \texttt{car} };
% …
\node[bodynode] (last) at (-5,2) { \texttt{cdr} };
% …
\node[bodynode] (last) at (-4,3.4) { \texttt{cdr} };
% …
\node[bodynode] (last) at (-2.5,3) { \texttt{cdr} };
% …
\node[bodynode] (last) at (0,2.5) { \texttt{car} };
% …
\node[bodynode] (last) at (2,4) { \texttt{cdr} };
% …
\node[bodynode] (last) at (5,2.5) { \texttt{car} };
% …
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And with a combination of them all you could save also the repeated `bodynode` addition:

```
\tikzset{bodynode/.style={body,minimum width=1cm}}% self-defined style
\begin{tikzpicture}
% …
\begin{scope}[every node/.style=bodynode]% scope and pre-defined style calling
                                         % self-defined style
\node (last) at (-6,3.5) { \texttt{car} };
% …
\node (last) at (-5,2) { \texttt{cdr} };
% …
\node (last) at (-4,3.4) { \texttt{cdr} };
% …
\node (last) at (-2.5,3) { \texttt{cdr} };
% …
\node (last) at (0,2.5) { \texttt{car} };
% …
\node (last) at (2,4) { \texttt{cdr} };
% …
\node (last) at (5,2.5) { \texttt{car} };
% …
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```